# Asking question and immediate answering

Tags: discussion, self-answer

**Is it good practice to "ask" a question (create new one) and immediately answer it?**

Background:

- I experiance some problem. Try to search some favorite sources for answer.
- I can't find any existing answer, so I perform larger research, learn new stuff and finally find resolution.
- As it take some time, I would like to share the resolution to help others.

Comment: When you ask a new question, there's an option you can mark to "self-answer" the question. Which is not frowned on- If it is a good question with a well written answer, go for it!

Comment: But remember, the question still has to stand on its own.  If the question isn't coherent enough to figure out what you're asking, it's still going to get closed, even if you self answer it.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out, if the downvotes mean the question is simply wrong (and I just cannot see it) or something else is unusual... It probably influence me next time I resolve another problem.

Comment: @f: Wouldn't it be the summit of irony if a self-answered question is closed for "being unclear what you ask"? "This does not answer the question", on the answer, comes close second :D

Comment: @Jongware - asker's own answers routinely get flagged as not an answer, sometimes because they are unclear but mostly because there are many reviewers (and not just new ones) who don't bother to take time to understand what they are reviewing.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you are allowed to answer your own question in a Q&A fashion - assuming the question is good otherwise. There's a checkbox for "answer your own question" in the "Ask Question" interface.